# Why does iOS AVAudioPlayer's prepareToPlay method return false?

Tags: ios, ios7, avaudioplayer

I have an array of audio players that plays one of when a user hits a certain location. However, when I call [prepareToPlay] on my player object, it sometimes returns false - the behaviour seems very erratic and unpredictable and I'd like to know what are the reasons it would return false.

My code looks like:

```
i = // some loop var
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[[MyAudio getSharedAudio] audioPlayers] objectAtIndex:i];
if (player != nil && ![[MyAudio getSharedAudio] isPlaying]) {
   if ([player prepareToPlay]) {
       [player play];
   } else {
        NSLog(@"Not prepared.");
   }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to call `prepareToPlay` if you call `play` immediately after that